# Pandas loop exact column iteration

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have this kind of code, which check for value in column A. If condition is met then the code check for value in the other column of the same row and copy the value from that column to replace value in column A:

```
counter = 0

list_of_winners = []

for each in data.iterrows():
    winner = data.iloc[counter, 5]

    if winner == 'Red':
        vitazr = data.iloc[counter, 0]
        list_of_winners.append(vitazr)

    elif winner == 'Blue':
        vitazb = data.iloc[counter, 1]
        list_of_winners.append(vitazb)

    elif winner == 'Draw':
        draw = str('Draw')
        list_of_winners.append(draw)

    else:

        pass

    counter += 1
```

The solution works for me and I am able to create a list and then that list put into original Dataframe and replace the values I looped thru.

What I want to ask.... Isn t there some other more elegant and shorter way to attack/address this problem?

Comment: Someone might be able to answer without it, but I would like to see how the dataframe looks like, in order to see what can be done without iterating over the rows. Otherwise, `for i, row in data.iterrows()`, `i` should replace `counter`

Answer (score 0):

You can do an `np.select`:

```
list_of_winners = np.select([data.iloc[:,5] == 'Red', 
                             data.iloc[:,5] == 'Blue',
                             data.iloc[:,5] == 'Draw'],
                            [data.iloc[:,0], data.iloc[:, 1], 'Draw',
                            default=None
                           )
```